# Problems creating a token on solana through the SPL on the command line

Tags: solana

I have a problem. When I use spl-token create-token, it shows:

error: No such file or directory (os error 2).

I've funded a solana wallet in Phantom to create the account. I also made sure to install all dependencies and checked if they were installed, yet it keeps showing the error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue when getting started, and means that no keypair has been configured for the Solana CLI just yet.  Please follow the instructions to setup your keypair at https://docs.solana.com/wallet-guide/paper-wallet#creating-a-paper-wallet, then the command should work.